# Show child component ONLY IF something in Parent's state is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render a child component only if a condition in the parent component's state is true. please see my code below. What is the advised way to accomplish this?

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
      return {playing: false}
   },

   render() {
     return(
        <div>
            //only render ChildComponentOne if this.state.playing is true
            <ChildComponentOne />
            <ChildComponentTwo/>
        </div>
      )
    }
});
```

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Comment: @TomFenech nice, i clearly didn't look very hard! thanks!

Comment: https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react/